# How do I defeat the noonwraith in the Devil by the Well?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've taken a contract to get rid of a noonwraith by a well, only the wraith disappeared after a few hits.

I proceeded to examine my surroundings and found the burned corpse of some dog or wolf, as well as a diary which appears to have been written by a woman.

I jumped into the well and found the bracelet described in the diary I had found earlier, then escaped from the well.

I then went to talk to the guy who put out the contract, as this was where my quest marker was pointing me to strangely enough. There, I learned about the reason *why* I was supposed to get rid of the wraith.

Back at the well, I noticed I could pull out a skeleton hanging inside; the skeleton belongs to a woman and is missing an arm.

---

This is where I'm stuck. Every time I return to the well at noon, the wraith fights me at full health, then disappears after a few hits.

Apparently, I'm supposed to burn the skeleton with the bracelet, but I can only examine the skeleton (after which Geralt will notice the missing arm where the bracelet should be) and casting Igni on the remains does nothing.

I'm suspecting the quest is bugged. From the looks of it, I'm expected to find the bracelet, but I already have it.

Is there something I've missed? Is the quest bugged? How am I supposed to defeat the wraith, if it constantly flees then returns the next day at full health?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some more researching, I found an interesting post on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/699808-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71828230?page=3#35), namely:

> I spent a while on this. I searched everything and even fought it once. I had to reread my bestiary to trigger the body burning interaction.

And sure enough, after reading the bestiary entry for the Devil by the Well (again), a cutscene was triggered and now I can burn the skeleton instead of just examining it.

---

#### TL;DR

Read the bestiary ***after*** reading the diary, finding the bracelet, and pulling out the skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

I too got bugged up on this quest as I stumbled on the village just exploring. I looted all the buildings and without much thought tried to jump in the well and subsequently found the bracelet. Then spent hours running around in circles trying to find evidence of the wraith after I went and talk to the guy.

Turns out I needed to go back and encounter the wraith at Noon for our first confrontation. which I did.

Then the entries showed up in my bestiary and I could read them and everything worked from there as advertised.

Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

I just completed this quest last night.

It sounds like you did some stuff out of order and maybe that's gummed up the works.  When I arrived at the village I had already spoken to the quest giver and then I used witcher senses to discover the diary and pull up the skeleton before entering the well.

You're prompted to jump into the well at that point.

I'm thinking that now that you've recovered the skeleton you need to go back into the well to advance things properly so you can have the cutscene where Geralt lights the remains and bracelet on fire.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I summoned the Noonwraith by burning the corpse, not by returning at noon - seems like your quest might be bugged.

From my journal, it seems that the steps to completion are as follows:

- Ask Odolan about the contract.
- Find the spirit that haunts the well.
- Use your Witcher Senses to examine the well.
- Find evidence of the spirit's presence using your Witcher Senses.
- Read the entry about noonwraiths in the Bestiary.
- Find out what binds the noonwraith to the ruined village.
- Go down the well and look for something that belonged to the dead woman using your Witcher Senses.
- Find a way out of the cave.
- Leave the cave.
- Prepare to fight the noonwraith and light a fire near the well.
- Light a fire to destroy the noonwraith's bones and bracelet.
- Defeat the noonwraith.
- Take a trophy from the noonwraith.
- Return to Odolan for a reward.

Sounds like you're bugged (as you say) at finding the bracelet. What does your journal currently say you've completed?

Comment: @nolonar: Sounds like you just needed to go through the steps. Nice one on figuring it out!

Comment: True, but only for reading the bestiary entry. It's a bug that'll likely confuse a lot of people, myself included. Thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: Unsure it's a bug - it does seem to be listed in the journal, and I remember reading it (though I do this habitually when I get new entries, tbh). `5. Read the entry about noonwraiths in the Bestiary.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the well to retrieve the bracelet. It's almost right where you land after jumping down. Use your Witcher sense - the red object is likely to be the whole left arm, climb up some where cross over the other pond and swim all the way the other end to surface up. Swim quickly as you'll run out of breathe and die.

I had the problem of noonwraith disappearing, so I ran away far enough that the game prompted me to go back to the well and dotted line on the mini map to guide me back, wraith reappeared and killed it.

Answer (score 0):

to stop the disappearing use the sign that sets the trap. the wraith will turn to human form. read this in the diary, found after looting the near by houses. I cannot find the ingredient for the potion that should be taking before fighting the wraith.In the bestiary, when clicking on the wraith, there's a drop down that shows the 3 items to make it easier to beat the wraith.